# How to properly convert key string to bs58 to unit8 in jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am working with Solana Blockchain in JavaScript.

I have the following key string address that I want to decode or convert to **BASE58** to **UINT8 Decoder**. How can I achieve that in JavaScript or even via jQuery?

```
<script>
var address = "9vpsmXhZYMpvhCKiVoX5U8b1iKpfwJaFpPEEXF7hRm9N";
//var bs58_decode(address);

/*
My result should look something like below
{
132,167, 105, 60, 17, 211, 120, 243, 197, 99, 113, 34, 76, 127, 190, 18, 91, 246,
    121, 93, 189, 55, 165, 129, 196, 104, 25, 157, 209, 168, 165, 149,
]
*/

</script>
```

Comment: Use some npm packages https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits goes to the author of this simple lib which you can find here https://gist.github.com/diafygi/90a3e80ca1c2793220e5/

```js
var from_b58 = function(
    S,            //Base58 encoded string input
    A             //Base58 characters (i.e. "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz")
) {
    var d = [],   //the array for storing the stream of decoded bytes
        b = [],   //the result byte array that will be returned
        i,        //the iterator variable for the base58 string
        j,        //the iterator variable for the byte array (d)
        c,        //the carry amount variable that is used to overflow from the current byte to the next byte
        n;        //a temporary placeholder variable for the current byte
    for(i in S) { //loop through each base58 character in the input string
        j = 0,                             //reset the byte iterator
        c = A.indexOf( S[i] );             //set the initial carry amount equal to the current base58 digit
        if(c < 0)                          //see if the base58 digit lookup is invalid (-1)
            return undefined;              //if invalid base58 digit, bail out and return undefined
        c || b.length ^ i ? i : b.push(0); //prepend the result array with a zero if the base58 digit is zero and non-zero characters haven't been seen yet (to ensure correct decode length)
        while(j in d || c) {               //start looping through the bytes until there are no more bytes and no carry amount
            n = d[j];                      //set the placeholder for the current byte
            n = n ? n * 58 + c : c;        //shift the current byte 58 units and add the carry amount (or just add the carry amount if this is a new byte)
            c = n >> 8;                    //find the new carry amount (1-byte shift of current byte value)
            d[j] = n % 256;                //reset the current byte to the remainder (the carry amount will pass on the overflow)
            j++                            //iterate to the next byte
        }
    }
    while(j--)               //since the byte array is backwards, loop through it in reverse order
        b.push( d[j] );      //append each byte to the result
    return new Uint8Array(b) //return the final byte array in Uint8Array format
}

// example
var mapping = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";

console.log(from_b58("9vpsmXhZYMpvhCKiVoX5U8b1iKpfwJaFpPEEXF7hRm9N", mapping));
```